# Get current line width in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opentk

This might look a simple question but I searched everywhere and can't find how to get the current line width using OpenTK.

I know that `GL.LineWidth(lw)` will set the current line width.

I found an enum named `All.LineWidth`.

But I didn't find out how to use it...!

I'll continue looking but if someone can help me... please do!

Comment: A language tag would be very helpful in getting you an answer. I added the c# tag because of the opentk tag wiki. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Comment: Ho my stars! You edited and changed my question...! I didn't know that was possible... well thanks... I'd prefer un answer... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ouff! I found it!!!

```
float currentLineWidth = GL.GetFloat(GetPName.LineWidth);
```

As incredible as it may seam, I couldn't find this in the OpenTK doc...!

PS: please don't edit out my 'ouff', I like it... :-D

PS2: and don't give this answer negative points, I'm sure it will be useful to other people

Comment: The [OpenGL reference pages](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/) are a very useful resuorce. See [glGet](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGet.xml). OpenTK gives you a lite version of the manpages in its intellisense documentation.